# Replacing string in a file

Tags: command-line, scripts

I wrote the following command:

```
rpl -x'.txt' '0 ' '-1 ' /home/administrator/temp/myText.txt
```

However I get an error message:

```
Usage: rpl [options] old_string new_string target_file(s)

rpl: error: no such option: -1
```

Why does it consider `-1` as an option and not a string? How to solve this?

Also, is there a way to replace all the strings in the text that **begin** with `0` with `-1`?

Comment: A.B. answered your first question already. As for the second one I think you'll have to switch to a more powerful tool such as `sed` or `perl`

Comment: Those are two questions. Please make a second question for the second part.

Comment: @A.B.: Thanks. I've posted a new question
|http://askubuntu.com/questions/623068/how-to-replace-all-strings-in-a-file-that-begin-with-some-prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the strings starts with a `-` you need put `--` as the last argument BEFORE the string. This will prevent the options parser from treating the string as a command- line option.

<sub>[Source](http://www.laffeycomputer.com/rpl.html)</sub>

```
rpl -x'.txt' '0 ' -- '-1 ' /home/administrator/temp/myText.txt
```

---

> Also, is there a way to replace all the strings in the text
>   that begin with 0 with -1?

As @kos said:

> you'll have to switch to a more powerful tool
>   such as sed or perl

But that's another question. **;)**

Comment: This will replace all the 0 characters at the start of a line, OP wants to replace a whole string starting with 0 non necessarily at the start of the line

Comment: Also it's hard to see this but OP put a space after the string to match and the string to replace ([you can see this by looking at the original post's raw source file](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/a9e29327-5624-4ede-bd51-c430cdc09ae3/view-source))

Comment: @kos Really hard to detect. I just use my smartphone. The second part of the question should be asked as a new question anyway.