# How to replace all strings in a file that begin with some prefix

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Example:

```
1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12
```

I want to replace all strings that **begin** with `2:` to `2:0`.

Output:

```
1:20 2:0 3:0.432 2:0 10:12
```

Comment: What about strings matching `2:` exactly? Should those be replaced?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/((^| )2:)[^ ]*/\10/g' in > out
```

Also, as inspired by [souravc's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/623077/380067), if there is **not** a chance of a `2:` substring after the start of a string **not** containing a leading `2:` substring (e.g. there is **not** a chance of a `1:202:25` string, which the following shortened command would replace to `1:202:0`), the command might be shortened to this:

```
sed -E 's/2:[^ ]*/2:0/g' in > out
```

---

**Command #1 / #2 breakdown**:

- `-E`: makes `sed` intepret the pattern as an ERE (Extended Regular Expression) pattern;
- `> out`: redirects `stdout` to `out`;

**`sed` command #1 breakdown**:

- `s`: asserts to performs a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `(`: starts the capturing group
- `(`: starts grouping the allowed strings
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `|`: separates the second allowed string
- : matches a  character
- `)`: stops grouping the allowed strings
- `2`: matches a `2` character
- `:`: matches a `:` character
- `)`: stops the capturing group
- `[^ ]*`: matches any number of characters not
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `\1`: backreference replaced with the first capturing group
- `0`: adds a `0` character
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the pattern flags
- `g`: asserts to perform the substitution globally, i.e. to substitute each occurence of the pattern in the line

**`sed` command #2 breakdown**:

- `s`: asserts to performs a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `2`: matches a `2` character
- `:`: matches a `:` character
- `[^ ]*`: matches any number of characters not
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `2:0`: adds a `2:0` string
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the pattern flags
- `g`: asserts to perform the substitution globally, i.e. to substitute each occurence of the pattern in the line

Comment: Quick as always :) +1

Answer (score 4):

This one liner using `sed`

```
sed -i.bkp 's/2:\([0-9]*\)\|2:\(-\)\([0-9]*\)/2:0/g' input_file
```

will **in line replace globally** in `input_file` keep a backup file named `input_file.bkp` at the same directory.

This can be further shorten using extended regexes as [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623068/how-to-replace-all-strings-in-a-file-that-begin-with-some-prefix#comment882601_623077) by kos, as

```
sed -ri.bkp 's/2:\-?[0-9]*/2:0/g' input_file
```

Comment: If you want to match both strings starting with `2:` and `2:-` just make the `-` optional matching using extended regexes (`-r` option); also you don't need to capture anything since you're not replacing anything: `sed -ri.bkp 's/2:\-?[0-9]*/2:0/g' input_file`

Answer (score 2):

I would use a basic `awk` loop:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i~/^2:/ && $i="2:0"}1' file
1:20 2:0 3:0.432 2:0 10:12
```

This loops through all the fields. Whenever one of them starts with `2:`, it replaces all of it with `2:0`. Finally, the `1` stands for True, so that all the line is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re
with open('test_dir/unix_se.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print re.sub(r'(?:(?<=(?: 2:))|(?<=(?:^2:)))[^ ]*', '0', line).rstrip()
```

Here we haves used the `re.sub` function of `re` module.

- `re.sub()` has the pattern `sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
- As we will not be using the values inside the group further, we have used the non-capturing group notation `(?:)`
- `(?:(?<=(?: 2:))|(?<=(?:^2:)))` uses the zero width positive look behind to match `2:` at the start or followed by a space.
- `[^ ]*` will match zero or more characters before space, after `2:` and then replace them with `0`.

Here is an example:

Input:

```
2:456 1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12
1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12 2:543 2:-78
```

Output:

```
2:0 1:20 2:0 3:0.432 2:0 10:12
1:20 2:0 3:0.432 2:0 10:12 2:0 2:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx @kos for the `sed` version:

Some little modifications for the `perl` way:

```
perl -pe 's/((^|\s)2:)[^\s]*/${1}0/g' testdata
```

Write back with:

```
perl -i -pe 's/((^|\s)2:)[^\s]*/${1}0/g' testdata
```

*Explanation:*

```
((^|\s)2:)[^\s]*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZEne-NuzPprF5QAp)</sub>

- 1st Capturing group `((^|\s)2:)`

  - 2nd Capturing group `(^|\s)`
  - 1st Alternative: `^`

    `^` assert position at start of the string
  - 2nd Alternative: `\s`

    `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

  `2:` matches the characters `2:` literally
- `[^\s]*` match a single character not present in the list below

  Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

  `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

---

Or with a *Positive Lookbehind*, thx @steeldriver

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=2:)\S*/0/g' testdata
```

*Explanation*

```
(?<=2:)\S*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `(?<=2:)` Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched

  `2:` matches the characters `2`: literally
- `\S*` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`

  Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

<sub>[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QTUJqAB6IQb2tuQr)</sub>

Comment: Couldn't you just use `s/(?<=2:)\S*/0/g` (replace any sequences of non-whitespace characters following `2:` with `0`)?

Comment: @steeldriver No nevermind, I misinterpreted your statement, your suggestion is good

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, lookbehind and lookahead are great.

Comment: @kos actually I maybe should have suggested `S+` rather than `S*` which will 'replace' an *empty* string following `2:` i.e. `2:` becomes `2:0`, which may not be the intended behaviour

Comment: @steeldriver I agree. OP should clarify this